# Check if a value is not in a list in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a function in ssrs that totals up all the values that are not in a certain list.
The function below is that I have but it is not seeming to work.

=sum(iif(Fields!Codes.Value <> ["700","200","300","400","500"], 1,0))

Comment: you can't compare a list of values like that. You'll need to test each value something like `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Codes.Value <> 700 AND Fields!Codes.Value <> 200 AND ..etc, 1, 0))`